# Why this procedure does not work properly? INSTR and SUBSTR issues

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I made this procedure:

```
create or replace procedure calculate_vertices(vertices VARCHAR2) AS
    pos2 INTEGER;
    pos1 INTEGER := 1;
    posDash INTEGER;
    lat VARCHAR2(20);
    lon VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    loop
        pos2:=INSTR(vertices,'@',pos1);
        exit when pos2 = 0;
        posDash := INSTR (vertices,'-',pos1);
        lat := SUBSTR(vertices,pos1,pos2-(posDash+1));
        dbms_output.put_line(lat);
        lon := SUBSTR(vertices,posDash+1,pos2-(posDash+1));
        dbms_output.put_line(lon);
        pos1 := pos2+1;
    end loop;
END;
```

then i called it as follows:

```
exec calculate_vertices('122.23-243.345@222.22-323@');
```

The result expected is:

```
122.23
243.345
222.22
323
```

But the real output is:

```
122.23-
243.345
222
323
```

How is it possible?

EDIT: I noticed it put in the variable LAT the same number of characters of the variable LON. Why?

Comment: `substr` works like this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm ;-) - seriously, you should edit the question title :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
lat := SUBSTR(vertices,pos1,pos2-(posDash+1));
```

is wrong, it should be

```
lat := SUBSTR(vertices,pos1,posDash -pos1);
```

just think, what does the position of the @ matter for the length of the string before the dash.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, `REGEXP_COUNT` in a single select instead of your PL/SQL block.

```
 WITH t (str)
     AS (SELECT '122.23-243.345@222.22-323@'
         FROM   dual)
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^-@]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
FROM   t
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, '[^-@]+');
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/UMT77632)